# org.powermock.api.mockito.ClassNotPreparedException at PowerMockito.mockStatic() when upgrading jdk8 to JDK11

Tags: powermockito, openjdk-11, mockstatic

I am using `PowerMockito.mockStatic(LogServiceImpl)` in my unit test code written in SPOCK framework. Even i declared `@PrepareForTest([LogServiceImpl])` at class level, i am getting `org.powermock.api.mockito.ClassNotPreparedException`.

Earlier it was working fine in JDK8, But when i am upgrading to open jdk 11 facing this issue.

This is the powermock version used in build.gradle file

```
   testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule-agent:2.0.5'
   testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.5'
```

I tried the steps given in

https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/933

https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/901

Still could not resolve it.. Please help me

Comment: are you using junit4/5 at all?

Comment: using junit 4 in my project.

Comment: See if the info here helps you? https://automationrhapsody.com/mock-static-methods-junit-powermock-example/ More detail needed on the question - code sample would be useful. It doesn't look like a dependency issue... more like a code issue as you're getting "ClassNotPreparedException" suggesting something isn't configured correctly - possibly not using the correct `PowerMockRunner.class` but hard to say without being able to see what you've currently got